# case when with count

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a quick sql data as below,

```
Customerid,Type
1,Adult
1,Adult
2,Adult
3,Adult
4,Teenager
4,Adult
```

I want the query that lists those customer no.s that do not have any other Type associated with them. For eg. 1 as only Adult associated with, same with 2. But 3 and 4 have multiple Types associated with them.
I am trying to get an output as below.

```
Customerid,Type
1,Adult
2,Adult
3,null
```

How should we tackle this.

Comment: Why `3` has `null` ? & why `4` not included in result ? please explain the logic.

Comment: explain logic it's easy to understand. thanks

Comment: Sorry, updated the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want:

```
select customerid
    , (case when min(type) = max(type) then min(type) end) as type
from table t
group by customerid;
```